# How to get facebook like sliding menu without using third party files in ios?

Tags: ios

I'm struck to implement it. I want to display a menu, which is already pushed into navigation controller. I know i have to use transition with animation method in which i have to increase the width from 0 to required value. But this is not helpful coz navigation controller takes care of presenting VC when we pop it. So how to implement it in ios?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate `UIWindow` for the menu, so you do not interfere with the `UINavigationController`.
You can have the menu behind your content window and move the content window to make the menu visible.